# No connection string named 'DbEntities' could be found in the application config file

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

First off, I don't think this is a dupe;
I know I have to copy the connectionstring into the Web.config root file, I have done so.

Using EF6.0 on .Net framework 4.0, Web MVC 4 project > BLL > DAL

Everything works on my developer machine, it also works on 2 different TST environments. But for some reason the VAL release does not work and throws this error.

Now, DEV & TST connecto to the same Db, so the connectionstring is exactly the same, but for VAL I have to change the PWD inside the connectionstring. That is the ONLY difference between the TST & VAL deployment.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong? Could it be a server related issue?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pfew, I figured it out; it had to do with the EntityFramework namespace wildcard (*) in the ConnectionString's metadata definition.

As i understand it; with a wildcard, it is possible that IIS attempts to read the required DLL before it is actually loaded. Correctly setting the namespace will avoid this issue.

Apparently, on my machine and the test environment if loaded the DLL beforehand, while on the VAL environment it did not, hard one to track down, I'll tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the password contains special characters that need to be escaped ?

Seeing as this is the only difference, this might be the problem.

Greetings.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that, sadly I'm not allowed to view the password, the deployment team changes this in my config. But it has the same pwd-rules as TST and that's alphanumerical